# How do I change the value of a range input

Tags: javascript

How to associate input range with scrolling images? When scrolling the input range, the images move, you need to make the input range change when scrolling the images

```js
var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll-range");

scroll.oninput = function() {
  var panel = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");

  var total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
  var percentage = total * (this.value / 100);

  panel.scrollLeft = percentage;
}
```

```css
#scrolling-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 1em 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-x: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-scroll">
  <div class="bems-scroller scroll-panel">
    <div class="scroll-content" id="scrolling-container">
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form class="rangeSlider">
  <input class="scroll-range" id="scroll-range" type="range">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you fix your snippet please? Some of your html elements seems to be missing.

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot about the input, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reflect the scroll to the input range use

- the `"scroll"` Event
- the math is quite simple: `percent = panelScrollLeft / scrollAvail * 100`
- Don't forget the `<li>` is invalid inside `<div>`. Use a list element instead like `<ul>`
- Most importantly, don't ever use `on*` handlers like `oninput`, `onscroll` etc., unless you create brand new elements from in-memory. Always use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Otherwise you might at some point override the already assigned event handlers.

```js
const elRange = document.querySelector("#scroll-range");
const elPanel = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");

elRange.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const tot = elPanel.scrollWidth - elPanel.offsetWidth;
  const pct = tot * elRange.value / 100;
  elPanel.scrollLeft = pct;
});

elPanel.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const tot = elPanel.scrollWidth - elPanel.offsetWidth;
  const pct = elPanel.scrollLeft / tot * 100;
  elRange.value = pct;
});
```

```css
#scrolling-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 1em 0;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scroll-content" id="scrolling-container">
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
    <div class="title">name and more</div>
  </li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
    <div class="title">name and more</div>
  </li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
    <div class="title">name and more</div>
  </li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
    <div class="title">name and more</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<input class="scroll-range" id="scroll-range" type="range" value="0">
```

- Also, as suggested by other answers try not to use `const tot = elPanel.scrollWidth - elPanel.offsetWidth;` outside of your functions (i.e: at the top of your file). Websites are **responsive** nowadays and it's always best to recalculate such a value on the fly. It's not an expensive operation since you're just accessing element properties values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let scroll = document.getElementById("scroll-range");
let container = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");
let total = container.scrollWidth - container.offsetWidth;

scroll.oninput = function() {
  container.scrollLeft = total * (this.value / 100);
}

container.onscroll = function() {
  scroll.value = (container.scrollLeft / total) * 100
}
```

```css
#scrolling-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 1em 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-x: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-scroll">
  <div class="bems-scroller scroll-panel">
    <div class="scroll-content" id="scrolling-container">
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/125">
        <div class="title">name and more</div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form class="rangeSlider">
  <input class="scroll-range" id="scroll-range" type="range">
</form>
```

Added on scroll function for div